# Tweepy does not handle 429 HTTP error (Too many Requests)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, http-status-code-429

I am currently using Tweepy library, and I launched it since several days. However after a while, I received the following message between each tweet collected:

> HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests

Or

> Service not available

I thought set as True the function `wait_on_rate_limit` while handle this kind of thing, or maybe it does not take account of 429 error ? I just requested about 10 terms in my filter, which returns around 1 tweet per 5-10 sec maximum.

How can I handle this kind of issue ? There is my piece of code btw:

```
streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=StreamListener(), timeout=3000000000)
streamer.filter(None,terms)

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    status_wrapper = TextWrapper(width=60, initial_indent='    ', subsequent_indent='    ')

def on_status(self, status):
    print ('{} {} - {}'.format(status.author.screen_name, status.created_at,status.text))
    saveTweet(status)
def on_disconnect(self, notice):
    print ("Disconnect: {}".format(notice))
    return

def on_warning(self, notice):
    print ("Warning: {}".format(notice))
    return

def on_exception(self, exception):
    print ("Exception: ".format(exception))
    return
def on_error(self, status_code):
    if (status_code == 403):
         print("Limit probably reached")
    else:
         print("Error occured > {}".format(status_code))
    return False
```

Comment: I also have the following message now between tweets collected `Service not available`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi!

For those who have the same issue, just upgrade Tweepy ! I raised an issue on the Github's Tweepy project, and it has been solved. Please see issue [#791](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/791) for more information